# Rewriting integral as linear operator

Tags: integration

Reading [Kajiya paper "The Rendering equation"](http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/~leopini/DISCIPLINAS/IA725/ia725-12010/kajiya-SIG86-p143.pdf).
We have integral equation:

$$I(x,x') = g(x,x') [e(x,x') + \int_Sp(x,x',x'')I(x',x'')dx''] (1)$$

Meaning of terms does not really matter for this question.

We want to get approximate solution. We rewrite (1) as

$$ I = ge  + gMI (2)$$

where M is the linear operator given by the integral in eq.(1) I don't understand this transition. What is linear operator in the most simple terms?

Comment: M is linear operator nature of which I want to find out. I is function that gives light intensity from direction x'' to direction x'. (2) - second equation.

Comment: most likey the wheightfunction $p$ is approximated as a delta function $p(x,x',x'')\approx\delta(x'-x'')M(x,x')$